Can I change the maximum Paper size for my Brother HL-L3230CDW Laser Printer - I want to print banners several metres long
In the print settings there is no option a for a banner print, If I select custom page size it only allows 35cm - about A4 length.
There is a manual feed tray so I can feed my paper roll there if I can get the printer to accept it.
I've tried setting the custom paper size via the printer dialog.
